# jQuery: hovering for submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, hover

I want to hover all my submenus while using the hover concept. I just got fade in only for the text but the background just won't fade in. Can anyone help me? This is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('ul.dynamic').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css({ display: "none" }).fadeIn();
        })
     });
</script>
```

Comment: He wants the menu item to flash off and then back on when mouseovered.

Answer (score 0):

Your code mostly works.

http://jsfiddle.net/V3H8A/2/

If you just want the individual menu items, not the whole menu to flash you need to change your selector to "ul.dynamic li"

Answer (score -1):

in the "ul" You must create span with text, and

replace

```
$(this).css({ display: "none" }).fadeIn();
```

with

```
$("span", this).css({ display: "none" }).fadeIn();
```

Comment: i used that to but still cant get